# Riemann integrability criteria

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Thinking back about limits and the original definition of the limit I thought that the Reimann integral (for some bound function $f$ in $[a,b]$) could be defined using limit-like definition. I found one definition and proved the equivalence of the two:

for any $\epsilon >0$ exists a partition $P$ for which $U(P)-L(P)<\epsilon$. where $L$ and $P$ are the lower and upper Darboux sums.

**My Question**

then I found this theorem for equivalence:

for every $\epsilon >0$ exists some $\delta >0$ such that $U(P)-L(P)<\epsilon$ for any partition $P$,  $||P||<\delta$.

I was not able to prove this one, how can on prove this theorem?

Comment: Are there any conditions on $P$?

Comment: In the theorem I want to prove? yes, $||P||<\delta$ as stated (in other words $\lambda (P)<\delta$) meaning the size of largest $\Delta x$ in $P$ is smaller than $\delta$

Comment: Sorry, I meant is this theorem supposed to hold for any arbitrary function (whose domain we are creating P over)

Comment: The second equivalence seems weaker than the one you already proved, no? The conditions needed for the first equivalence are a strict subset of the first.

Comment: @Bey oh sorry, $f$ is bound in $[a,b]$ and this is where we are asking about it's integrability. I agree they are similar (they are equivilant as stated) but I did find it useful in many cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the proof can be found [here](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math2060b/Notes%202%20Riemann%20Integration%202015.pdf) in theorem 2.4 (2.4').